# Regular expression (For digits and characters)

Tags: javascript, html

I've been experimenting with a local sign in/log in system and I've hit a error. I was trying to make a regular expression that checks if the user's username and password contain 8 characters and 2 numbers. I really am not sure how to do that but this is all my code I've been able too put togheter.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>      
 <form id='form'>
    <title>Sign Up #1</title>
    <h3>Simple Signup system</h3>
    <div>
      <label>Username:</label>
      <input type="text" name="text1" id = "username">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>Password:</label>
      <input type="text" name="text2" id = "password">
    <div>
 <button type="button" id="subBtn">Sign Up!</button>
  </form>
</body>
<script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

My JS code:

```
var t = 'everything good, loging in'

var f = 'something is not right, try again.'

var tf = 'not-set'

var statment = /^[a-zA-Z]*$/

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('subBtn').addEventListener('click', onSubmit);
}
// main
function onSubmit() {

if (document.getElementById('username').value.includes(Number)) {
    tf = 'True'
} else {
    tf = 'False'
}

if (document.getElementById('username').value.includes(statment)) {
    tf.push('True')
} else {
    tf.push('False')
}

if (tf = ['True', 'True']) {

  alert('Good to go, redirecting')

} else {

  alert('Username does not meet the standards for creating a account!')
 }
 document.forms['forms1'].submit()
}
```

EDIT: Was able to redo a part of the code, I'm still using regex to check for letters because I'm not sure how to do it without it.
Current error: 'first can't be a Regular Expression'.

Comment: (In advance I apologize for any bad English/poor wording.)

Comment: Regex is not the right tool. You should just write a few if statements checking the various conditions.

Comment: Alright, will try that!

Comment: You have 2 opening `<form>` tags.

Comment: I've fixed that but still doesn't change my issue, now I'm getting ''first can't be a Regular Expression''.

Comment: Your new error is that you're passing a regex to `String.prototype.includes`, which takes a string. You're also passing `Number` to `includes,` which will not work. This, for example, would: `var numCount = value.split('').map(Number).filter(Boolean).length`